# How to execute the function while terminating the process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals

Let's assume that I've got a function that does some work.

```py
def exporter_methods(return_dict):
    def handle_exit(*args):
        return_dict["error"] = True
        print("Program were aborted by signal:", signal)

    print("signal registration")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)

    for i in range(30):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("hello")
```

I want to create a new process and run this function inside it. And then, I want to be able to kill the process by time out and do some work (`handle_exit()`) inside my function before the process is terminated.

So I created a recursion function to check whether it is time to terminate the process by time out or not.

```py
def recursion(process, i, max_time):
    i += 1
    process.join(1)
    if i > max_time:
        if process.is_alive():
            print('Terminating child {}'.format(process.pid))
            process.terminate()
            process.join()
            print('Child {} ended with {}'.format(
                process.pid,
                process.exitcode))
            return None
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        if process.is_alive():
            target = recursion(process, i, max_time)
            if target is None:
                return None
            else:
                return 1
        else:
            return 1
```

And then, I start the process using the following code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=exporter_methods,
                                   args=(return_dict, ))
    print("Start process")
    proc.start()
    i = 0

    flag = recursion(proc, i, max_time=4)
```

I expect the process to be created, and the function will print "hello" every 2 seconds. After that, when 4 seconds is over, my recursion function will try to terminate the process using `process.terminate()`, and then I expect that the handle_exit function will be raised, and it will print "Program was aborted by signal." After that process will be terminated, and the program will stop. But it doesn't happen right now. I've got the following results:

> Start process
> signal registration
> hello
> hello
> Terminating child 7767
> Program were aborted by signal: <module 'signal' from '/Users/aleksandrgordeev/opt/miniconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.9/signal.py'
> hello
> hello
> hello

So it doesn't work, could you explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you post a question tagged with `multiprocessing`, Stack Overflow requests that you also tag the question with the platform you are running on because there are huge differences between Windows and Linux. But I am going to take an educated guess that you are running under Linux since your code produces different results under Windows.

For Linux your `exporter_methods` function should test a flag such as `quit` and if set to `True` should break out of its loop. Therefore, the `handle_exit` function should set that flag to `True` when it is called:

```py
import signal
import multiprocessing
import time

def exporter_methods(return_dict):
    quit = False

    def handle_exit(*args):
        nonlocal quit
        return_dict["error"] = True
        print("Program were aborted by signal:", signal)
        quit = True

    print("signal registration")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)

    for i in range(30):
        if quit:
            break
        time.sleep(2)
        if quit:
            break
        print("hello")

def recursion(process, i, max_time):
    i += 1
    process.join(1)
    if i > max_time:
        if process.is_alive():
            print('Terminating child {}'.format(process.pid))
            process.terminate()
            process.join()
            print('Child {} ended with {}'.format(
                process.pid,
                process.exitcode))
            return None
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        if process.is_alive():
            target = recursion(process, i, max_time)
            if target is None:
                return None
            else:
                return 1
        else:
            return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=exporter_methods,
                                   args=(return_dict, ))
    print("Start process")
    proc.start()
    i = 0

    flag = recursion(proc, i, max_time=4)
    print(flag)
    print(return_dict)
```

Prints:

```None
Start process
signal registration
hello
hello
Terminating child 80
Program were aborted by signal: <module 'signal' from '/home/Booboo/Python-3.9.7/Lib/signal.py'>
Child 80 ended with 0
None
{'error': True}
```

On Windows, the printout is:

```None
Start process
signal registration
hello
hello
Terminating child 23624
Child 23624 ended with -15
None
{}
```

**It appears that in Windows the `handle_exit` function is never even called.**